# Parsing dict keys and values and writing/appending data to a file

Tags: python

I have the following and need some guidance on python implementation..I clearly documented the algorithm and the expected output..any inputs are truly appreciated..

```
data_changes ={'305403': ['302180'], '312994': ['311957'], '311957': ['312621'] }
modem_changes = {'305403': [], '313113': [], '312994': ['253036', '312591'], '311957': []}

for keys that are present in both data_changes and modem_changes:
        write data to a file "file.txt" in the order key-->data_changes_values-->modem_changes_values

for keys that exist in only one of data_changes and modem_changes :
        append data to the same file "file.txt" key--> data_changes_values or key-->modem_changes values

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-

Create a text file with the following data

305403 302180
312994 311957 253036 312591
311957 312621
313113
```

Following is what I tried but not serving my purpose...

```
build_dep_list= [i
for k, v in itertools.chain.from_iterable(d.iteritems() for d in (data_changes, modem_changes))
for i in [k] + (v or [])
if i]
print "BUILD LIST"
print list(set(build_dep_list))

CURRENT OUTPUT:-
['305403', '302180', '313113', '311957', '312621', '253036', '312994', '312591']
```

Comment: Make `set`s of the keys, then you can easily get intersection and symmetric difference and so on: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set Then just write to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Use `set`s...they will efficiently do the hard work of intersections and symmetric differences:

```
data_changes = {'305403': ['302180'], '312994': ['311957'], '311957': ['312621'] }
modem_changes = {'305403': [], '313113': [], '312994': ['253036', '312591'], '311957': []} 

dc_set = set(data_changes)
mc_set = set(modem_changes)

# open a file in append mode    
fh = open('myfile.txt', 'a')

for key in dc_set.intersection(mc_set):
    union_values = data_changes[key] + modem_changes[key]
    fh.write('%s,%s\n' % (key, ','.join(union_values)))

for key in dc_set.symmetric_difference(mc_set):
    dc_values = data_changes.get(key) or []
    mc_values = data_changes.get(key) or []
    union_values = dc_values + mc_values
    fh.write('%s,%s\n' % (key, ','.join(union_values)))

fh.close()
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

The first one is fairly straightforward since the keys are in both dicts.  In the other case, you don't know which dictionary the key will live.  The `get` method will attempt to fetch the value for the given key and return `None` if not found.  If not found, it will default to an empty list from the `or` statement.

Comment: I usually use: `dict.get(key, default)`, i.e `data_changes.get(key, [])`

Comment: @brianz - anyway we can easily modify the above code to write the output to a text file "file.txt"(Create the file when the file is not present)

Comment: I've updated the answer to write to a file.  You can read more about reading and writing files in Python here: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Answer (score 0):

The for loops can be written as:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    dc_keys = data_changes.keys()
    mc_keys = modem_changes.keys()

    for key in dc_keys:
        if key not in modem_changes.keys(): continue
        f.write('key-->' + ','.join(data_changes[key]) + '-->' + ','.join(modem_changes[key]) + '\n')

    for key in mc_keys:    
        if key in dc_keys: continue
        f.write('key-->' + ','.join(modem_changes[key]))

    for key in dc_keys:    
        if key in mc_keys: continue
        f.write('key-->' + ','.join(data_changes[key]))
```

I've updated the answer to use only lists as this better suits your needs. And as for file writing, I've updated it so that it actually writes to the file.

Comment: thanks...how to write to the file in that error?am sorry very new to python

Comment: The second for loop has a problem, in that you don't know which of the two dicts the key is in. (I guess you could try both and find out, but it seem silly!)

Comment: @Xaranke - why do you have the for key in mc_keys: and if key in modem_changes.keys(): continue twice?

Comment: I realized that...its fixed now.

Comment: @Xaranke - you are using with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:...so if the file doesnt exist it will throw an error..can we open it in such a mode that it will create the file "file.txt" if it doesnt exist